# Does the word 津波 (tsunami) have negative connotations?

Tags: words, culture

Or is it just a neutral term for tidal waves?

(I'm considering naming a JavaScript library `tsunami.js` – would it be offensive?)

Comment: I don't think it'd be any more offensive than the famous [神奈川沖浪裏](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa).

Comment: @istrasci, thanks! Maybe I should call it okinami.js (just to be safe).

Comment: I heard about a twitter client called [earthquake](https://github.com/jugyo/earthquake) and thought "Why would someone call something that?", but it was built by Japanese people in response to the 2011 earthquake and tsunami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "not necessarily"; but, it definitely doesn't have *positive* connotations...

One might think of it as `<= 0`.

---

**Update**

Hmm, evidence?  Well, the word "earthquake" is definitely not a positive word by itself, right?  It has more neutral or negative connotations (i.e.,`<= 0`).  But, I don't know how to provide evidence of that...

There is a word, アクセス津波 (access tsunami), which is when there are a lot of site views/accesses in a short period.  When used in this sense, I guess the blog owner would be happy :)

At any rate, I don't think you'll realistically be offending many people by using "tsunami" (unless your project is destructive, obviously).

By the way, what will your project be doing?

Comment: Thanks! I hoped for some evidence but your opinion matters, too.

Comment: Answer updated :)

Comment: If the word is sometimes used figuratively and represents the concept of power/energy/abundance, it's OK for me to use as well (the project is a waveform visualization). Thank you!